# Barchart wth Annotations in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I had developed BarCharts with annotations. Each bar is a one bar chart(displaying in attached jpeg). But i need total in one barchart with 4 bar series and annotations like a black line displaying in the middle (like,as shown in attached jpeg )

Please refer the below link.
http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/4872/chartsc.jpg
Data is comming from the server and need plot into the charts, but i could not find the solution, how to do it.

Please let me know any one have solution on the same.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Do you mean that you want all 4 series on a single chart?

Comment: 4 Bar series displaying in the jpeg, 4 bar series [Average Read LAtency, Average Write latency, Total read IOPS, Total Write IOPs] .

Comment: Yes, it is displaying 4 bar series in single chart, But i need with Annotations (each bar series divide into 3 parts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had changed to barchart to progressBar. so Noe this issueis tempararoly resolved. Thanks to all for spending time to see and try to resolve it.